# Keeping node.js running

Tags: node.js, npm

During development it would be great to have node.js restarted automatically when changes occur in the applications directory. When the application is in production, node could be start just like normally. When the server is rebooted with or without intention, node needs obviously to be restarted.

I've heard about and tried both `forever` and `supervisor`. Supervisor works good, but I can't make it to start during boot. Forever on the other hand ignores any changes in my directory.

Are there alternatives that are available that would do all this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

Below code was put in `/etc/init/myApplication.conf`:

```
# Enter below
respawn
console none

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  sudo always /var/www/backend/app.js > /var/www/backend/nodelog.log
end script
```

Always checks for changes in my node directory while this script ensures that always is started on boot.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently started using [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to manage my apps. You can export from Foreman to [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) which should solve your problem with handling reboots, etc. in a production environment (although I haven't done this myself yet.)

For automatically updating files on change, check out [always](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/always). (Then run always from your local Procfile through Foreman - that's my setup.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are likely to find anything that automatically starts node on boot, but depending on your OS, this isn't very difficult. Could you tell us what your OS is?

Comment: Sorry. It's Ubuntu 11.10 on the server